# Fresh install Code::Blocks release undefined reference to '_Unwind_Resume'

Tags: reference, undefined, release, codeblocks, resume

So I installed Code::Blocks with minGW v12.11 newest one. I can easly compile programs in debug mode but when I try release I get a lot of errors which i posted below. I would really appreciate reseponses.

```
obj\Release\koniec.o:koniec.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\koniec.o:koniec.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x43)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
obj\Release\nowa_gra.o:nowa_gra.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\nowa_gra.o:nowa_gra.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x43)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
obj\Release\pytania\pytanie_1.o:pytanie_1.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd5)||undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\pytania\pytanie_1.o:pytanie_1.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x9f)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
obj\Release\pytania\pytanie_2.o:pytanie_2.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd5)||undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\pytania\pytanie_2.o:pytanie_2.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x9f)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
obj\Release\pytania\pytanie_3.o:pytanie_3.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd5)||undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\pytania\pytanie_3.o:pytanie_3.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x9f)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
obj\Release\tabela_wynikow.o:tabela_wynikow.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\tabela_wynikow.o:tabela_wynikow.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\tabela_wynikow.o:tabela_wynikow.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\tabela_wynikow.o:tabela_wynikow.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x43)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
obj\Release\zapis.o:zapis.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\zapis.o:zapis.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\zapis.o:zapis.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
obj\Release\zapis.o:zapis.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x43)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
||=== Build finished: 18 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i opened some old projects and that's why it bugged when I made a new one it compiled smoothly.